# The method reprendre(List<EntiteRepriseDTO<BesoinAppro>>) in the type RepriseService is not applicable for the arguments (List<EntiteRepriseDTO<T>>)

Tags: java, list, generics, serializable

I need your help to resolve a java genericity problem.

I would like to correct the following error :
**The method reprendre(List<EntiteRepriseDTO>) in the type RepriseService is not applicable for the arguments (List<EntiteRepriseDTO>)**

The code that provokes this error :

```
    public class BesoinAppro implements Serializable { ... }

    public class EntiteRepriseDTO<T extends Serializable> { ... }
    
    @Stateless
    public class RepriseService
    {
        public <T extends Serializable> void reprendreOnglet(OngletExcel onglet, @Nonnull List<EntiteRepriseDTO<T>> listeEntite) {
            reprendre(listeEntite);   // the error appears here
        }
        
        private void reprendre(List<EntiteRepriseDTO<BesoinAppro>> produitsReprise)
        {
            // an implementation
        }
    }
```

The implementation forces me to give up theses method signatures.

Maybe it's impossible ...

Thank you for your help.
Nicolas

Comment: You have reprendre and reprendreProduits, are they meant to be the same? If they are, reprendre says that the list has to contain BesoinAppro, while reprendreOnglet says it can be any T. So what will happen if you call reprendreOnglet with a list of EntiteRepriseDTO<SomethingElse> and not BesoinAppro. Either reprendreOnglet only supports BesoinAppro, or reprendre supports everything.

Comment: @JPMoresmau thank you for your answer. @JPMoresmau, it's a bad copy/paste : i had corrected the code. `reprendre` is the method called
This code is a simplified version of the code. Actually, in `reprendreOnglet` there is an `if` that control that I can call `reprendre`

Comment: then you'll need to cast your list into the right type (List<EntiteRepriseDTO<BesoinAppro>>)listeEntite if you're really sure you have the right type...

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for your help and have a nice day.